# Rotate Element at Center

Tags: jointjs

I am trying to build a custom shape - a diamond that stays centered over the text in its label (bonus if we can make the shape expand as the label changes).

Right now, I am transforming a rectangle by 45 degrees to create the diamond. Problem is this seems to rotate around to top left corner and not the center point.

How can I make JointJS rotate this shape around it's center? Or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Here is a JSFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/dfqpbLyn/3/

```
var baseRhombus = joint.shapes.standard.Rectangle.define('crt.BaseRhombus',
    {
        attrs: {
            label: {
              textAnchor: 'middle',
              textVerticalAnchor: 'middle',
              fontSize: 25,
              text: 'Test'
            },
            body: { 
                strokeWidth: 1,
                stroke: 'green',
                fill: 'gray',
              //transform-origin: center center,
              transform: 'rotate(45, center, center)',
            }
        }
    },
    {
        markup: 
        [
            {
                tagName: 'rect',
                selector: 'body'
            },
            {
                tagName: 'text',
                selector: 'label'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        initialize: function (width, height, x, y) {
            var newElement = new this({
                id: 'g1',

                            position: {x:x, y:y},
                size: {width: width, height: height},
                //position: { x: x, y: y },
            });

            return newElement;
        }
    }
);


var baseRhombus = joint.shapes.crt.BaseRhombus.initialize(250, 250, 60, 50);
```

Thanks!
Will

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Used 
`transform: 'rotate(45, 50, 50)` on the body of my element, but calculated the transform origin based on the current width and height of the element. The documentation around transform was a bit difficult to find but once I found an example of it in use it became clear.